# How to add a update a column to add foreign keys in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating an Ebay clone project where users can bid on multiple products. When the auction time is up on a project, the user with the highest bid wins the product. Here are my current SQL tables I plan to use:

[image]

How would I create an SQL update command to add a product id to a users products_won column? This is the way I have now, but I doubt it would work:

[image]

I understand many to many and one to many relationships, but this seems like a one to many relationship. Since users can win multiple products, however products can only have one highest bidder? Because it seems like a one to many relationship, I don't believe I need to create a joining table. Appreciate any help

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a "bridging" table, `user_products`:

```
create table user_products (
    email text foreign key references users(email),
    product_id int foreign key references products(id)
);
```

Then to assign a product to a user, you simply insert into this table.

Having said that, you really want an auto-incremented integer id in the `users` table as well.  Strings are slightly less efficient for foreign key references.  Plus, you don't want PII used to identify records in any table that references a user.